# Java - When to use fixed size thread pool and variable size thread pool?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

In java ThreadPoolExecutor, what happens in the following two different scenarios?

```
1) Fixed Size ThreadPool
   CoreThreadPool size = 5
   MaximumThreadPool size = 5
   Queue size = unbounded
Maximum no.of threads that can run simultaneously=?

2) Variable size ThreadPool
   CoreThreadPool size = 5
   MaximumThreadPool size = 10
   Queue size = unbounded
Maximum no.of threads that can run simultaneously=?
```

Also when to use both these cases?

Comment: "If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full." - from [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). So **using an unbounded queue will never get the Thread count above corePoolSize** in the shown setup of variable size Threadpool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that the second setup allows your to run with a maximum of 10 threads; whereas the first one starts with 5; and will never create more than that.

You would use the first setup when you understand that you don't gain more performance/throughput/... when going for more threads. On the other hand, keep in mind that fixed size also means: there will always be 5 (or 10) threads around. In that sense, this kind of threadpool makes most sense in a "static" environment; where your "load" isn't heavily changing over time. You don't want 5 threads to do work that would be good for 10 threads, but you also do not want 10 threads to be idling most of the time, because 5 would be good enough.

In other words: it very much depends on your whole setup; on the incoming traffic, and many other factors how many threads give you "best" results. SO, when in doubt, you should do careful profiling; and test what changing **one** variable (like the max number of threads) changes for you. But of course: all of that requires that you have good means to measure the performance/behavior of your application.

Comment: I would add the hint that a fixed size Threadpool also does not let threads die when idle. So an _indicator_ would be if you expect (nearly) constant load, you'd go for fixed size. If you expect "bursts" **and** more threads are helpful in dealing with temporarily higher load, then you'll go with variable size, so you only have more threads temporarily while the "normal" load is handled by less threads.